# creating a copy constructor with abstract class

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to copy an Object, which will then be modified, without changing the original object. The relevant classes are:

```
abstract class Upgrade {}

class Shield: Upgrade
{
  public Shield(Shield a) {}
}
```

The problem is when another class wants to get an "Upgrade" object but the class doesnt know which object it get. For example:

```
public void AddUpgrade(Upgrade upgrade)
{
    for (int i = 0;i<Aliens.Count; i++)
    {
        Aliens[i].AddUpgrade(What should i put here?);
    }
}
```

i have to use copy constructor because i dont want all the aliens to share the same upgrade reference but the Upgrade is an abstract class, than what should i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `Upgrade` cloneable, i.e. add `Clone()` to it (every descendant will implement) and it will become something like:

```
Aliens[i].AddUpgrade(upgrade.Clone());
```

Comment: So are you saying, add a ``public abstract Upgrade Clone();`` statement to the ``Upgrade`` class, then implement in subclasses, as opposed to making the abstract class ``ICloneable``?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copy constructors, consider using a factory - either an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) or some [factory methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

These will allow you as much control over object construction as you wish, without tying you down to the inheritance chain (at least, not much).